# JWPlayer 7 Playlist on iPhone not playing (was playing)

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

Playlist was playing fine, actually on iPad it does play, but now it only plays the youtube video and stays full screen, while last week it played and then went to original player size and continued (not without a click of course), here is the code:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  "autostart": true,
  "repeat": true,
  "controls": true,
  "visualplaylist": true,
  "playlist": [{
      "file": "https://youtu.be/3R8mIlBnwng"
    },{
      "file": "http://162.220.219.35:8081/live/stream3.sdp/playlist.m3u8"
  }]
});
</script>
```

By the way I tried to invert the order, first streaming then video and it does not work either.

Comment: Could you include a link to a page that shows the problem? This isn't a known bug on JW Player's end, so it could be a number of things.

Comment: live URL: http://www.guatevision.com/jwplayer7.php iPad, iPadMini, Desktop, Laptop (whatever browser, even Microsoft Edge), Android Tablet and Cellphone, not on iPhone, just 1st video but does not jump or at least change to next one... :0(

Comment: With Chrome 51/OsX the second video starts correctly